# $\mu(\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty\omega:|g_n(\omega)-g(\omega)|>\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$ then $g_n\to g$ pointwise a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, pointwise-convergence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $g_n : \Omega \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}, n \in \mathbb{N}$
and $g : \Omega \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ be measurable functions.

Prove that if $$\forall \varepsilon,\exists N:\mu(\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty\{\omega:|g_n(\omega)-g(\omega)|>\varepsilon\})<\varepsilon$$

then $g_n \to g$ pointwise almost everywhere.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: You may *show your work* by taking $\epsilon$ as $\epsilon/2^k$.

Comment: Did you check that this is not a duplicate? Also do you assume that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$?

Comment: If you could redirect me to a duplicate, that would be really nice. Why would $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ change anything about this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with notice that 
    \begin{align*}
  &\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty \{ \omega : |g_n(\omega) - g(\omega)| > \varepsilon \} 
  = \{ \omega : \sup_{n\geq N}|g_n(\omega) - g(\omega)| > \varepsilon \}\\
  &\supset \{ \omega : \limsup_{n\to +\infty}|g_n(\omega) - g(\omega)| > \varepsilon \}
  \supset \{ \omega : \limsup_{n\to +\infty}|g_n(\omega) - g(\omega)| > 0 \}\\
  &=\{ \omega : g_n(\omega) \not\to g(\omega) \}.
 \end{align*}
    Thus by the monotonicity of $ \mu $
    $$ \mu ( \{ \omega : g_n(\omega) \not\to g(\omega) \} ) < \varepsilon, $$
    which completes the proof.